# How to display custom fields in a protected post wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've a protected post. However, I would still like to show/display the custom fields in the protected post.

How can I do that? Below is my code,

```
<div class="portb-thumbb">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumb-s'); ?></a>
<?php } ?></div>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h2 class="single-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php
echo "For more information on " . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'extrainfo', true)."<br/><br/>";
?>
<div class="meta-info-date"><?php the_time('F j Y,') ?><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"> <?php comments_number ('0','1','%'); ?> Comments</a></div>
<div class="singlet-entry"><?php the_content(); ?> </div>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <p><?php _e('No posts by this author.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Appreciate any helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the post requires a password, and whether the password has been provided, using the <kbd>[post_password_required()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_password_required)</kbd> function.

Here's your updated code.

```
<p class="extrainfo">
  <?php if ( post_password_required() ) {
    echo "For more information on " . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'extrainfo', true); 
    }
  ?>
</p>
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt response! i like to rephase my question again, I would still like to show the custom field even though a password is not provided.

Comment: Oh, then your current code should work. According to the Wordpress docs on Password Protection, custom field values are not password protected and default behaviour is to show them regardless of whether the actual post is password protected. "Protect Custom Fields - 
WordPress does not print a password-protected post's Content or Excerpt until the correct password is entered. **But a post's Custom Field(s) data is not protected, and can still show.** " From: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection#Protect_Custom_Fields

Comment: Shiva, Weird. I've updated my question. This is my exact code. It does not show the custom field in my single.php page.

Comment: Glad you did. Curious, what was the issue?